# Pandas evaluating two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with two variables ID,DATE. I'm using following code to get the rows which meets two conditions.

1) It has to be first occurrence of ID

2) It has to fall in specific date range.

```
data_2 = data_1.groupby('ID').first() & datetime.date(2012,1,1) < data_1['date'] < datetime.date(2012,2,25)
```

It is throwing type error. Could any one suggest why i'm getting type error?

Thanks.

Comment: `datetime.date(2012,2,31)` is out of range for Feb.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even correcting the date will give the same error. I will edit my question.

Comment: First, I think you have to put each condition in between parentheses: `(data_1.groupby('ID').first()) & (...)`. Second, I think you should split your second condition in two: `(datetime.date(2012,1,1) < data_1['date']) & (data_1['date'] < ...)`

Comment: Does `((data_1.groupby('ID').first()['date'] > datetime.date(2012,1,1)) & (data_1.groupby('ID').first()['date'] < datetime.date(2012,2,25)))` generate the proper boolean mask?

Comment: In general you should post the full error message (and full stack trace).

Comment: Hi Nickil, yes, i'm getting proper boolean mask using the code provided, what if we want to get the data instead of boolean as an output?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),50),'DATE':pd.date_range('2012-01-01',periods=50)}) 

mask_first = df.DATE.isin(df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].first()) 
    mask_range = (df.DATE >= pd.to_datetime('2012-01-05')) & (df.DATE <= pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07'))
    df[mask_first & mask_range]
```

Output:

```
        DATE ID
4 2012-01-05  A
```